# How to change the appearance of PROC PRINT output in SAS to "notepad" style?

Tags: sas, output

If I run a basic `proc print` in SAS, I get an output that looks something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to (easily) change the appearance of this to look something like this (taken from [here](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug11/ds/ds09.pdf)):

[image]

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're in display manager, click Tools -> Options -> Preferences -> Results, then check the box next to "create listing". This will send your output to the listing destination which was the default destination before SAS 9.2. You should be able to save your listing output as text like the example you posted.

If you're in Enterprise Guide, click Tools -> Options -> Results then select the "Text output" box.

Comment: Thank you! Saving the "list" file got me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using SAS Studio just click on the top right corner menu icon, then:

Preferences -> Results

And select `Monospace` in HTML Output Style.

Comment: The `Monospace` style *almost* got what I wanted. :) The "create listing" from DWal ended up working for me. Thanks for your help though.